# Passing variable elements to variables with the elements' names

Tags: php

Is there a way to pass all array's elements to variables with the elements' names?
For example if I have the following array:

```
$test['name']
$test['phone']
$test['address']
etc..
```

I want a shortcut for typing this:

```
$name = $test['name'];
$phone = $test['phone'];
$address = $test['address'];
etc..
```

Comment: The functionality you are looking for is provided by the [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) PHP function.

Comment: Although I would add that this is a bad idea and rarely is what is actually needed - IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can use [$$](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```
$test['name'];
$test['phone'];
$test['address'];


$test['name'] = "John";
$test['phone'] = "987987987";
$test['address'] = "Asheville";

foreach($test as $key=>$val){
  $$key = $test[$key];
}
echo $phone;
```